# What is the meaning of "objectively better" in this sentence

Tags: pun

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> If you ask a modern adherent to this rule why, exactly, you aren't supposed to end a sentence with a preposition, they merely goggle at you as if you had just asked why you aren't supposed to lick electrical sockets. Because it is *objectively better* not to, that's why.

The fact that the "objectively better" part is italicised as well as answer both the above mentioned questions makes me think that the author is making a pun here. Regarding the latter question, I think the word "objective" means "based on experience and facts" and regarding the former question, I think it somewhat relates to the "objective case" we learn in grammar.  But I am still not sure. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is this. An object normally comes after a preposition. Therefore the pun is where do you put the object if the preposition is at the end. "Because it is **object**ively better not to"

Explanation. A preposition can be understood as anywhere a dog can be in relation to its doghouse.
A dog can be:
in the doghouse
around the doghouse
near the doghouse
on the doghouse. All of these preposition examples show where the dog is in relation to its doghouse (**The Object**).

The second to pun is to **object** to, (dislike) **licking Electrical sockets**

object[enter link description here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/object)
[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/object) verb [ I ] UK ​  /əbˈdʒekt/ US ​  /əbˈdʒekt/
**​to feel** or express opposition to **or dislike of something** or someone:

Comment: Sorry I did not answer the second question as I was concentrating on the English not the humour. My bad. I have edited the answer now.